# How do I style two elements into different styles by hovering over one of them? Without JavaScript

Tags: html, css

I have to do a task but I can not finish it.
No Javascript is allowed.
Here is the task:

> When hovering over an image or a link do the following:
>
> - make image opacity: 0.4;
> - make link text color yellow;

I made it so that these rules are applied when you hover over the image. But I can't seem to achieve the same effect when hovering over a link.

Do I have to change the structure of the elements?
Do I have to use `:not` pseudo-class?
I wonder if it's even possible to do this without Javascript.

```css
body {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.card {
  width: 150px;
}

.image {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.description {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: limegreen;
}

.image:hover~.description .link,
.link:hover {
  color: #ff0;
}

.image:hover {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="image">img</div>
  <div class="description">
    <a class="link" href=#>some link</a>
    <div class="text">Fulfilled direction use continual set.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is already working. Hovering over the link and it correctly changs colour.

Comment: if you want a single hover function then insert them in a single div

Comment: You could simply make the `.card` the link, that would be an easy workaround.

Comment: @ SteveTomlin, you did not read correctly: **"But I can't seem to achieve the same effect when hovering over a link."** Here is the problem

Comment: what do u mean by same effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution with pointer-events that does not change structure of html and respect :hover none if you go over description:

```
.card {
    pointer-events: none;
}
.image, .link{
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

And after you set the `:hover` on the whole `.card`:

```
.card:hover .description .link {
    color: #ff0;
}
.card:hover .image {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

### DEMO

```css
body {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.card {
    width: 150px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.image, .link{
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.image {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.description {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: limegreen;
}

.card:hover .description .link {
    color: #ff0;
}
.card:hover .image {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="image">img</div>
  <div class="description">
    <a class="link" href=#>some link</a>
    <div class="text">Fulfilled direction use continual set.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First time hearing about pointer-events. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Run this Code snippet and let me know if this is what you desired. :)

```css
   body {
      font-size: 1.2em;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .card {
        width: 150px;
    }

    .image {
        height: 80px;
      background-color: tomato;
    }

    .description {
      height: 80px;
      background-color: limegreen;
    }

    .image:hover ~ .description .link,
    .link:hover {
        color: #ff0;
    }

    .image:hover {
        opacity: 0.4;
        color: #ff0;
    }
    
    .description:hover {
        opacity: 0.4;
        }
```

```html
        <div class="card">
          <div class="image">img</div>
          <div class="description">
            <a class="link" href=#>some link</a>
            <div class="text">Fulfilled direction use continual set.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Pete suggested the best solution